# AJAX Accordion renders scrollbars in Firefox but not IE

Tags: .net, ajax, firefox, controls, accordion

Having a bit of a problem with the AJAX Accordion Control...

I have two panes, one of which is open by default, but in Firefox it displays scrollbars across both axis - when you extend the second panel, these disappear. In IE no scrollbars are rendered - which is what i'm aiming for!

Using FireBug, I can see that when the Accordion Control is rendered on the page the div has the following attributes applied: "overflow: auto; height: auto;" - changing overflow to 'hidden' solves the problem.

[Annoying scrollbars! http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5052/sosanta.gif](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5052/sosanta.gif)

[Full size image here](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5052/sosanta.gif)

Now my issue is, because the Accordion Control is rendered on the fly, how can I force the Overflow property to be hidden? I've tried setting a style to the Accordion itself, and also the Divs it contains and resides in but had no luck :(

Thanks for any advise on this one - going crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... with al nik's suggestions, I sifted through all my code - in the Header of pane 2 of the Accordion (which only contains an image) I had specified a Height property (height="100px" the same height as the image) - for some reason in Firefox, this caused the scrollbar to appear despite the AutoSize property being set to 'none'.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the accordion-plugin documentation to see if there is a configuration parameter that you can set to achieve what you want.
If [THIS](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) is what you're using you can set the AutoSize to 'none' and the accordion will adapt to the content width.

Comment: Thanks - I am using that control - however I did try the AutoSize paramater and unfortunately it had no effect :(

Comment: It looks like the browser is messing around with padding/margin. With firebug try to remove padding/margins/borders from the content that is loaded in the accordion (start from the 1st element and go down through the dom). When/If you find the padding/margin/border that is giving the problem try to remove it from the page that is loaded as content